# How to add custom script in the index.html at the end of the body when using the npm run build command in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, npm-build, angularbuild

Is there anyway that we can append a script file in the index.html after we build our angular app?

things that i have tried:

```
{
 "build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": { ... },
  "configurations": {
   "production": {
    "fileReplacements": [{
     "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
     "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }],
    "scripts": ["src/assets/scripts/my-custom-script.js"],
    ...
    }
  }
 }
}
```

and this:

```
// main.ts
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
  const scriptEl = window.document.createElement('script');
  scriptEl.src = 'https://js.intercomcdn.com/vendors-app-modern.28279aba.js';
  window.document.body.appendChild(scriptEl);
}
```

in both proposed solutions my dist/projectName/index.html file remained unchanged after i ran npm run build command...

Comment: Does the scripts not in a bundled js file ?

Comment: The second example works. You're not seeing the script in dist/index.html only because it gets added at runtime, not during build.

Answer (score 1):

On of the possible solution is to use the power of fileReplacements mechanism. Just create index.prod.html and add it into

```
"fileReplacements": [{
  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
},
{
  "replace": "src/index.html",
  "with": "src/index.prod.html"
}]
```

And add whatever you need in index.prod.html file

Answer (score 0):

You can add the script directly in the index.html

```
 <script src="./assets/scripts/my-custom-script.js"></script>
```

### UPDATED

In my opinion, you have one option :

Create a folder named **dynamic_script** in the `assets` and then put 2 files there

**1-** Your js file (like ARRS5125-MLL-YourJsfile.js)

**2-** A JSON file (like info.json), set the name of your file here

```
{
 "filename":"ARRS5125-MLL-YourJsfile.js"
}
```

**NOTE**

Whenever the name of your script is changed, change the filename in the JSON file
based on your js name.

Now, You can dynamically load your js file as below

**Step 1:**
Create a service :

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class LoadScriptService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getJsonFileName(): Promise<any> {
        return this.http.get('./assets/dynamic_script/info.json').toPromise();
    }


    loadScript(name: string) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            //load script
            let script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = `/assets/dynamic_script/${name}`;
            if (script.readyState) {  //IE
                script.onreadystatechange = () => {
                    if (script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete") {
                        script.onreadystatechange = null;
                        resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded' });
                    }
                };
            } else {  //Others
                script.onload = () => {
                    resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded' });
                };
            }
            script.onerror = (error: any) => resolve({ script: name, loaded: false, status: 'Loaded' });
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        });
    }

}
```

**Step 2:** In you component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private scriptService: LoadScriptService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  private async loadJsonAndScript() {
    const fileInfo = await this.scriptService.getJsonFileName();
    this.scriptService.loadScript(fileInfo.fileName)
  }

  load() {
    this.loadJsonAndScript();
  }
}
```

**NOTE:**

After building your project whenever you add the new js file in the  **dynamic_script** then open the `info.json` and replace the new name manually.

Comment: But then i would need to add it manually every time after building... that's not the desired functionality.

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because that script wont be always the same, there are some numbers in the name that will change all the time,  it is something like a version, and because of that i need a dynamic way of adding that script or any other in the future.

Comment: I updated my answer. please check and if you have any problem let me know.

Comment: Please follow this answer you will get the result